# Spring-Security OpenId won't work

Tags: java, spring-security, openid

I'm trying to implement OpenId in Spring Security by following the tutorial [here](http://krams915.blogspot.se/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with_13.html), but I can't seem to get it to work. When I test my implementation, it seems to discover the URL for the OpenId provider, but it never redirects me to the login page for that provider. Instead I get returned to my login page with my "You have entered an invalid username or password!" error.

Here's what my logger says when I try to login with, say, coraythan@aol.com:

```
[qtp760167714-19] INFO org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery - Starting discovery on URL identifier: http://aol.com/
[qtp760167714-19] WARN org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: C326ACEE663C4C976739D4E51A500DA7][domain: www.aol.com][path: /aol][expiry: null]". Illegal path attribute "/aol". Path of origin: "/"
[qtp760167714-19] WARN org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: D07CE2D83B0A58663C6EAA557FCFAD14][domain: www.aol.com][path: /aol][expiry: null]". Illegal path attribute "/aol". Path of origin: "/"
```

The second time I try it logs a different thing to the console:

```
[qtp760167714-21] INFO org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery - Starting discovery on URL identifier: http://aol.com/
[qtp760167714-21] INFO org.openid4java.util.HttpCache - Returning cached HEAD response for http://aol.com/
[qtp760167714-21] INFO org.openid4java.util.HttpCache - Returning cached GET response for http://aol.com/
[qtp760167714-21] INFO org.openid4java.util.HttpCache - Returning cached GET response for https://api.screenname.aol.com/auth/openid/xrds
```

Trying it with a myOpenid account give slightly different messages:

```
[qtp760167714-16] INFO org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery - Starting discovery on URL identifier: http://coraythan.myopenid.com/
```

And the second time:

```
[qtp1540619773-25] INFO org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery - Starting discovery on URL identifier: http://coraythan.myopenid.com/
[qtp1540619773-25] INFO org.openid4java.util.HttpCache - Returning cached HEAD response for http://coraythan.myopenid.com/
[qtp1540619773-25] INFO org.openid4java.util.HttpCache - Returning cached GET response for http://coraythan.myopenid.com/?xrds=1
```

Using the "google login" option gives the same sort of issue. It looks identical to what I see from OpenId, but with google stuff instead.

Strangely, trying to login with a yahoo e-mail is even worse because throws a stack trace! The stacktrace seems to be thrown from OpenId4Java (the backing openid implementation used by Spring Security Openid).

For a yahoo e-mail some of what the stack trace looks like is:

```
[qtp665820578-23] INFO org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery - Starting discovery on URL identifier: http://yahoo.com/
2013-03-02 18:58:27.060:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:Error for /j_spring_openid_security_check
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cyberneko/html/HTMLTagBalancingListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.parseDocument(CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.java:99)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.getHtmlMeta(CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.java:42)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.getHtmlMeta(YadisResolver.java:325)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:453)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:252)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
    at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:542)
    at org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer.beginConsumption(OpenID4JavaConsumer.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
[...]
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancingListener
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.parseDocument(CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.java:99)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.getHtmlMeta(CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.java:42)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.getHtmlMeta(YadisResolver.java:325)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:453)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:252)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
    at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:542)
    at org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer.beginConsumption(OpenID4JavaConsumer.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
```

Here's my spring security xml:

```
<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security -->
<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied">

    <!-- TODO fix all these URLs open to anyone -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/VAADIN/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <!-- Admin only URLs -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <!-- Logged in User only URLs -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/endpoint/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/game/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <security:openid-login 
        login-page="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/?error=true" 
        default-target-url="/game" />

    <security:logout 
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/" 
        logout-url="/logout" />

</security:http>

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the 
    database -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"
    id="passwordEncoder" />

<!-- An in-memory list of users. No need to access an external database 
    layer. See Spring Security 3.1 Reference 5.2.1 In-Memory Authentication -->
<!-- john's password is admin, while jane;s password is user -->
<security:user-service id="userDetailsService">
    <!-- user name is based on the returned OpenID identifier from Google -->
    <security:user
        name="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItxxioJSDLFJLjxcksdfjOpAASDFosSSoJ0E"
        password="" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />

</security:user-service>
```

I have the following servlet mapping and spring security filters in my web.xml:

```
<!-- spring gets everything else -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

If there's any other information I can provide, I'd be glad to! I really want to get this working, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Strangely if I try switching the post method URL input value (which is what OpenId4Java performs discovery on) I can get vastly different results. For example, "https://accounts.gibberish/" just causes the console to log "performing discovery" over and over again. "https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth" causes the same exact thing as myOpenId and "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id", but then "https://accounts.google.com/" causes a stacktrace with an error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cyberneko/html/HTMLTagBalancingListener"

Comment: Also, my program's start up shows this: [main] WARN org.openid4java.server.RealmVerifier - RP discovery / realm validation disabled;   I don't think that's the issue though.

Comment: It looks like your classpath is missing the nekohtml jar. Why don't you use the OpenID sample that comes with the lastest Spring Security release? It should be up to date and maintained.

Comment: I think I took a look at it and then didn't import it into eclipse to look because it is a gradle project, and I haven't worked with gradle projects before. I'll try to figure out how to import it and take a look, though.

Comment: Woo hoo! I was able to get it to work using the spring security openId sample! And not only that, but that example clearly looks and works a lot nicer thanks to the OpenId selector project it uses. If you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. (As it may not have directly answered my question, but it definitely solved my problem.)

Comment: @CorayThan Mind posting a working eclipse sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenID sample](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#openid-sample) that comes with Spring Security is probably a better starting point and is customized for both Google and Yahoo.

To get it running, checkout out the source using git

```
git clone git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security.git
```

Then it should be as simple as installing [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) and running the following commands.

```
cd spring-security
gradle build
cd samples/openid
gradle jettyRun
```

Pointing your browser at `http://localhost:8080/openid` should then give you the OpenID selector UI to choose the provider you want to authenticate with.

Comment: OpenID sample link is dead

Comment: A working link to the Open ID example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/html5/